# I closed the app after Interstitial showed but it still call onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() method

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am showing Interstitial ads after the splash screen in my application. I am using the below code to show ads.

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        com.google.android.gms.ads.interstitial.InterstitialAd.load(
                this,
                getResources().getString(R.string.Splash_ID),
                adRequest,
                new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull com.google.android.gms.ads.interstitial.InterstitialAd interstitialAd1) {
                        // The mInterstitialAd reference will be null until
                        // an ad is loaded.
                        mInterstitial = interstitialAd1;
                        mInterstitial.show(SplashActivity.this);
                        Log.e("ADDA12", "onAdLoaded");
                        interstitialAd1.setFullScreenContentCallback(
                                new FullScreenContentCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                                        mInterstitial = null;
                                        Log.e("ADDA12", "The ad was dismissed.");
                                        finish();
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(AdError adError) {
                                        mInterstitial = null;
                                        Log.e("ADDA12", "The ad failed to show.");
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
                                        Log.e("ADDA12", "The ad was shown.");
                                    }
                                });
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                        // Handle the error
                        Log.e("ADDA12 11", loadAdError.getMessage());
                        mInterstitial = null;
                    }
                });
```

Now I run the app on my device and the app shows ads after the splash screen then instead of closing(dismissing) the ads I am closing the application from the background and app still calling `onAdDismissedFullScreenContent()`

So after ads showed, if I close application from the background instead of dismissing the ads then the app will be closed but it will call `onAdDismissedFullScreenContent()` and open `MainActivity`.

Comment: remove the [finish()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#finish()) call on the onAdDismissedFullScreenContent. I should mention that your interstitial ad implementation goes against AdMob policies. [Read More](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201362?hl=en&ref_topic=2936214)

Comment: I don't understand how `onAdDismissedFullScreenContent()` is called if i killed application  after ads is shown

Comment: how about you set setFullScreenContentCallback before, showing ad. I am sorry I dont understand you killing the app, is it with code? IMPORTANT: set setFullScreenContentCallback on this custom variable  _mInterstitial_ and not the _interstitialAd1_

Comment: no i am not killing app with code i am testing app and I am killing app after ads shown